# How to convert strings of different lengths into timestamps of different precisions for pandas interpolation?

Tags: python, pandas

I have three different strings

```
'0300' , '0600' and '03125455'.
```

I want to convert them into pandas timestamps as

```
'03:00:0000' , '06:00:0000' and  '03:12:5455'
```

so that I can interpolate corresponding values of variables for the first two at the third one. I do not have any date data. What I am using is the following

```
time1 = pd.to_datetime('2018050103000000')  # Dummy date 2018-05-01
time2 = pd.to_datetime('2018050106000000')
timeX = pd.to_datetime('2018050103125455')

val1  = 100
val2  = 200

df    = pd.DataFrame( [(time1, val1) , (time2, val2)] , columns=['Times','Values'] ) 

df    = df.set_index('Times')
df    = pd.Series(df['Values'], index=df.index)
inter = df.resample('S').interpolate(method='linear')
valX  =interp.loc[timeX]
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

How should I properly convert these strings to datetime with or without using dummy dates? **I just need time values, not dates.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need.

**Ex:**

```
time_data = ['0300' , '0600', '03125455']
for t in time_data:
    print(pd.to_datetime(t.ljust(8, "0"), format="%H%M%S%f").strftime("%H:%M:%S%f"))
```

**Output:**

```
03:00:00000000
06:00:00000000
03:12:54550000
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but It is giving an error during interpolation  **TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'**

Answer (score 1):

Done in two steps

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame([('0300',100),('0600',200)], columns=['Times', 'Values'])

df
Out[25]:
  Times  Values
0  0300     100
1  0600     200
```

Convert to datetime column

```
df['Times2'] = df.Times.apply(lambda x:pd.to_datetime(x.ljust(8,'0'),format='%H%M%S%f'))


 Out[49]:
  Times  Values              Times2
0  0300     100 1900-01-01 03:00:00
1  0600     200 1900-01-01 06:00:00
```

Then convert datetime to just time columns

```
df['Times2'] = df.Times2.apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.time(x))

df
Out[51]:
  Times  Values    Times2
0  0300     100  03:00:00
1  0600     200  06:00:00
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @MichaelD. Its a bit lengthy but I can understand clearly what each step is doing. Thanks again